# Is it possible to use d3.js with gatsby.js framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, svg, gatsby

I'm in the process of creating a personal website/portfolio, and I stumbled upon the robust gatsby.js package.

I also have to visualize a complicated dataset for research purposes and I want to use d3.js, and include the dashboard I create in my Gatsby powered site.

It's possible to use d3 in react components -> https://medium.com/@Elijah_Meeks/interactive-applications-with-react-d3-f76f7b3ebc71

Theoretically,Gatsby should be able to support d3 integration, but my attempts thus far have failed.

Here is what I have tried:

Complete the Gatsby tutorials https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/

I am using a completed 4th tutorial site from the gatsbyjs documentation with the following additions

```
npm install --save d3
```

added utils/d3.js

file contents

```
import d3 from "d3"
module.exports = d3
```

I also added d3 to the gatsby-config.js plugins.

I run `gatsby develop`, and receive the following error, which hangs.

```
success delete html files from previous builds — 0.005 s
success open and validate gatsby-config.js — 0.003 s
(node:8725) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 2): Error: Unable to find plugin "d3"
(node:8725) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.
 In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any feedback would be helpful, if this is an intractable feat, what would be my path of least resistance to accomplish my goal of d3 integration and an easy personal site framework?

**UPDATE 09/08/17**

I switched to the Hello World! tutorial to debug the d3 issue. I have tried [d3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) and [d3-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-node) npm packages.

Upon adding `import d3 from "d3"` to my index.js file, I get two similar errors that occur after the bootstrap finishes.

Both errors loop in compile attempts and respectively output:

***d3 error***

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors  
These dependencies were not found:

* child_process in ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js

* fs in ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs
```

***d3-node error*** 
switch the import on index.js to "d3-node"

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 13 errors

These dependencies were not found:

* fs in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js, ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js and 3 others
* net in ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js, ./~/forever-agent/index.js and 1 other
* child_process in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
* tls in ./~/forever-agent/index.js, ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save fs net child_process tls

These relative modules were not found:

* ../file-api/FileReader-impl.js in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/FileReader.js
* ../events/MutationEvent-impl.js in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/MutationEvent.js
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem has to do with the fact that the most recent version of D3 v4 uses a bunch of node.js dependencies, as explained in this gatsby github issue:

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2107

The solution is to modify your webpack config so that it loads the correct version of d3.

I'm using D3 in a gatsby project to create a force-directed graph, and I discovered I could sidestep this issue by only loading the d3-force library instead of the entire d3 package. This is preferable anyways because it is anti-react to let D3 directly manipulate the DOM. A better approach is to use D3 for the calculation and react for the rendering as shown here:

https://medium.com/walmartlabs/d3v4-forcesimulation-with-react-8b1d84364721

Comment: Great answer. I've spent the past few months immersed in the rapidly evolving JavaScript ecosystem, and you nailed the issue. Thanks for the clarification! I might come back and hack at this project now.

Answer (score 5):

Only Gatsby plugins should be added to gatsby-config.js. For other regular NPM packages like D3, all you need to do is import them into your modules.

Comment: Hey @Kyle, I heard your talk on Software Engineering Daily, and I thought you grave a fantastic talk!  Back to the matter at hand, I have reread the Gatsby section on source plug-ins, and I have tried many other tweaks, but I haven't had luck yet. One of my colleagues suggest I use Jekyll rather than Gatsby since the Jekyll documentation is more extensive. While he may be correct, I like your work and I want to give it a shot. In one of your blog posts under the Route-based code splitting section you actually mention d3 (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/gatsby-v1/).

Comment: Please see my updated post. IMHO, adding a section in the tutorial demonstrating best practice for leveraging external nodes in concert with Gatsby would be very helpful.

Comment: Remove d3-node — it's for node.js not the browser.